# Copy folders from one directory to another within Docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Can anyone tell me how to move a folder from one Directory to another within a Docker container? I have a folder in the root directory of my Docker container:

```
    root/folder/folder1
```

I've created a folder called Source at the same container level as root. In my Dockerfile I'm trying to copy folder1 into Source as below:

```
    ADD root/folder/folder1/ /Source/
```

But I get an error saying that root/folder/folder1/ isn't a file or directory. I'm new to Docker, can anyone assist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ADD` instruction copy from outside the image into the image. The source should be in your contexte directory or, for `ADD`, an URL and Docker will download it (and extract it if it's an archive).

It's usually a good practice to use `COPY` instead of `ADD` most of the time.

In your case, as you want to copy a directory inside your docker image, you should execute a shell command for that: `RUN cp -r /root/folder/folder1 /Source` (or maybe create a link if you don't need to duplicate the content).

For more information about `ADD` vs `COPY`, you can read the [Dockerfile Best Practices from docker](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy)